# How to parse tsv file with python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a tsv file which includes some newline data.

```
111 222 333 "aaa"
444 555 666 "bb
b"
```

Here `b` on the third line is a newline character of `bb` on the second line, so they are one data:

The fourth value of first line:

```
aaa
```

The fourth value of second line:

```
bb
b
```

If I use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V paste to a excel file, it works well. But if I want to import the file using python, how to parse?

I have tried:

```
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open(file.tsv)]
for i in range(len(lines)):
    value = re.split(r'\t', lines[i]))
```

But the result was not good:

[image]

I want:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you meant by this: "Here b on the third line is a newline character of bb"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It knows about all the possible corner cases in CSV files like new lines in quoted fields. And it can delimit on tabs.

```
with open("file.tsv") as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter="\t", quotechar='"')
    for row in rd:
        print(row)
```

will correctly output:

```
['111', '222', '333', 'aaa']
['444', '555', '666', 'bb\nb']
```

Comment: to import csv module, add this at the top of your file: 
`import csv`

Answer (score 15):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv ("file.tsv", sep = '\t')
```

Comment: Also worth to mention that if you don't have  a header in your file, add header=None otherwise it might use the first row as a header

Answer (score 0):

Newline characters, when within the content (cell) of your .tsv/.csv, is usually enclosed in quotes. If not, standard parses might confuse it as the start of the next row. In your case, the line

```
for line in open(file.tsv)
```

automatically uses newline character as a separator.

If you are sure that the file only has 4 columns, you could simply read the entire text, split it based on tab, and then pull out 4 items at a time.

```
# read the entire text and split it based on tab
old_data = open("file.tsv").read().split('\t')

# Now group them 4 at a time
# This simple list comprehension creates a for loop with step size = num. of columns
# It then creates sublists of size 4 (num. columns) and puts it into the new list
new_data = [old_data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(old_data), 4)]
```

Ideally, you should close content that could have newlines in quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the real data is double quoted. I have edited the topic. I will read your method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scipy as sp
data = sp.genfromtxt("filename.tsv", delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: An explanation would help. But this _does_ seem like a good way to do it, from my limited knowledge.