# Add line to a TSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a TSV file that looks like that:

[image: TSV FILE]

With two columns, the first with headers and the second with values.
Basically, I have to add some lines, to add values (and headers) that I have calculated inside my Python script.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: Read the TSV file using pandas, append your lines and save it again. There are a lot of examples on how to use pandas to manipulate csv

Comment: Do you know how to use the csv module or with pandas.read_csv? If so, just use that but with the delimiter as   '\t'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358259/how-to-parse-tsv-file-with-python Maybe this helps?

Comment: How about posting the TSV text for easier writing of solutions?